# Максимальное количество значений в $in

Tags: mongodb

Возник вопрос: какое максимальное количество значений, которые можно поместить в `$in` в mongo?

```
{ $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] }
```

Comment: А какие причины считать, что оно вообще ограничено?

Comment: Нигде не описано, либо меня в гугле забанили. Но узнать надо бы.

Comment: Запустить и проверить - совсем не вариант?

Comment: Логично, что если бы был вариант - вопрос не был бы задан.
Если кроме припираний нечего ответить - не надо дурить голову.

Comment: Если бы мне было что ответить, то я бы написал ответ, а не комментарий ;)

Comment: Согласен с @Dmitriy. Проверьте. Любой скриптовый язык, адаптер для БД -- и вперёд, пробовать экспоненциально увеличивающиеся массивы. Как умрёт, бинарным поиском отследить, на каком числе.

Comment: а разве эти ограничения не документированы?

Answer (score 1):

В англоязычном SO энтузиасты [провели исследование](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5331549/5238378) и выяснили, что количество объектов в $in формально не ограничено, но, поскольку в качестве аргумента для `.find()` отсылается объект, на него тоже действует ограничение размера объектов в MongoDB в 16 Мб.

```
Object.bsonsize({ 'field' : { $in : [ value1, value2, ..., valueN] } })
```

Этот код даст вам размер вашего запроса. Вероятно, чем больше будет размер всяких `field` и `valueX`, тем меньше их влезет в запрос.

### Вывод:

Если ставить целью послать максимальное количество вариантов в `$in`, то один товарищ [утверждает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18495467/5238378), что **максимальное количество элементов в `$in` примерно равно 1,5 миллиону**

Если цель - практическое применение, то об ограничение можно спокойно игнорировать)